# Different formulas for two-sided mid $p$-value ($2\times2$ table setting)

Tags: p-value, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm interested in testing independence of two binary variables in a $2\times 2$ table: i.e. $H_0: \theta=1$ against the *two-sided* alternative $H_1:\theta\neq 1$, where $\theta$ is the odds-ratio. Suppose that the margins of the table are fixed, then the random variable for the number of hits among cases is given by $X\sim \text{HyperGeom}(n,N_1,N_2)$, where $n$ is the total number of hits, $N_1$ is the total number of cases and $N_2$ is the total number of controls. The hypergeometric pmf is given by 
$$
Pr(X=x)=\frac{\binom{N_1}{n}\binom{N_2}{n-x}}{\binom{N_1+N_2}{n}}
$$
for $\max(0,n-N_2)\leq x\leq \min(n,N_1)$.

For testing, I'm using the mid $p$-value as it is one way to reduce the conservativeness of the Fisher's exact test without resorting to randomized tests. Suppose that the observed number of hits among cases is $x_0$. I've seen two formulations of the *two-sided* mid $p$-value in the literature:

**Formulation 1**
[Eq 1.10](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A11n313.pdf) or [Section 2.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01701.pdf)
$$
p^{(1)}_{\text{mid}}(x_0)=\sum_{j:Pr(X=j)<Pr(X=x_0)} Pr(X=j) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j:Pr(X=j)=Pr(X=x_0)} Pr(X=j)
$$

**Formulation 2**
$$
p_{lt}(x_0) = Pr(X<x_0)+0.5~Pr(X=x_0)\\
p_{gt}(x_0) = Pr(X>x_0)+0.5~Pr(X=x_0)\\
p^{(2)}_{\text{mid}}(x_0)=2\min(p_{lt},p_{gt})=2\min(p_{lt},1-p_{lt})
$$
where the one-sided versions, $p_{lt}$ or $p_{gt}$, can be found in: [Eq 1.7](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A11n313.pdf) or [Section 5.1](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_gottard_2007a.pdf), to name a few.

Note that changing the 1/2 to 1 in Formulation 1 would get you back to the traditional Fisher's exact test two-sided $p$-value. It's interesting to note that Formulation 1 is the one used in [SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/67528/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_details98.htm#procstat.freq.freqexdef) `PROC FREQ`, but Formulation 2 is the one used in certain `R` packages such as `epitools::ormid.test` or `exact2x2::exact2x2`.

From a simple test on the $2\times 2$ table below in `R`, I noticed that these two functions sometimes don't produce the same $p$-values. In some tables, Formulation 1 is more conservative in that it yields a larger $p$-value than Formulation 2. In another setting, Formulation 1 can be much less conservative compared to Formulation 2. In the second setting, shown below, Formulation 2 is seen to be more conservative than the two-sided Fisher's exact test. This latter observation seems like an unwanted side-effect, if the goal is to reduce conservativeness.

**Question**
Which formulation is appropriate (and under what situations)?

**Code**

```
midpval_f1 <- function(ct){

  x <- ct[1,1]
  n <- sum(ct[1,])
  N1 <- sum(ct[,1])
  N2 <- sum(ct[,2])

  lo <- max(0L, n - N2)
  hi <- min(n, N1)

  support <- lo : hi
  out <- dhyper(support, N1, N2, n)

  pval <- sum(out[out < out[x - lo + 1]]) + 
            0.5*sum(out[out==out[x-lo+1]])

  return(pval)
}

midpval_f2 <- function(ct){

  x <- ct[1,1]
  n <- sum(ct[1,])
  N1 <- sum(ct[,1])
  N2 <- sum(ct[,2])

  plt <- phyper(x-1,N1,N2,n) + 0.5*dhyper(x,N1,N2,n)
  pgt <- phyper(x,N1,N2,n,lower.tail = FALSE) + 0.5*dhyper(x,N1,N2,n)

  pval <- 2*min(plt,pgt)
  return(pval)
}

test_ct <- matrix(c(3,5,7,9),ncol=2,byrow=T)

> midpval_f1(test_ct)
[1] 0.8366761
> midpval_f2(test_ct)
[1] 0.7956208

test_ct2 <- matrix(c(5,10,2,38),ncol=2,byrow=T)

> midpval_f1(test_ct2)
[1] 0.006789634
> midpval_f2(test_ct2)
[1] 0.01357927
> fisher.test(test_ct2)$p.value
[1] 0.012561
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding why it is worth so much time to take this approach.  After all, Fisher's "exact" test is not very accurate.  This simple 2x2 has plagued frequentist statisticians for decades.  It cries out for a simple Bayesian solution that automatically provides exact calculations.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - The $2\times 2$ analysis is part of a bigger framework - multiple testing. I'm developing a method involving a new multiple-testing testing framework to identify exomic regions which have enrichment/depletion of rare variants in cases/controls, and I want to use the mid $p$-value as my test statistic. It is somewhat related to gene-set analysis, where I have many such sets and I want to summarize the information in each set.

Comment: @stats134711 the good-old Pearson $\chi^2$ test is exactly what you want for that.  Its p-values are more accurate that Fisher's "exact" p-values and calculations are far, far faster.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I forgot to mention that I am working in the rare setting (MAF < 0.1%), with thousands of hypotheses (i.e. 2x2 tables) so it is quite likely I will get expected cell counts exactly zero. It is also my experience from simulations that the $\chi^2$ statistic is too liberal and does not always control the FDR (i.e. inflation). I am mostly curious why the use of formulations are varied in the software, as using one over the other may yield different results.

Comment: For the extreme case where one expected frequency is < 1 you can make a simple adjustment to the ultra-fast Pearson $\chi^2$ to make it again very accurate.  This involves multiplying it by $\frac{n-1}{n}$.  This has been discussed at length on this site.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - Thanks. I have actually never seen such a correction. I will look into it. Do you have any link to the posts you mention regarding this adjustment? I did a quick search and couldn't find any mention of it.

Comment: https://www.zotero.org/groups/2199991/feh/items/tag/fishers-exact-test